# Can I whitelist IP's using IIS running a PHP site?

Tags: php, iis, ip-address, whitelist

As outlined by this guys post, [blocking IP's via PHP](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/03/how-to-block-ip-addresses-with-php/) is pretty easy.

However, how can I do this, site wide, using IIS?

Here are my (big) caveats:

1. I do not have access to change the php.ini.  So I can't use auto_prepend feature.
2. I am on Windows with IIS so I can't use .htaccess.
3. I don't have any PHP "footer" which gets called on all of the scripts.  In fact, a lot of the pages are static HTML!

Is there any way I can use IIS to whitelist IP's?

The good news is that I have a static list of IP's to whitelist, so I wont need to easily change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can whitelist IP addresses in IIS, which should give you the results you want.

- In IIS 6.0, right-click your website and choose properties.
- Go To the Directory Security tab.
- Click Edit for "IP addresses and domain name restrictions"
- Click the "Denied access" radio button.
- Enter any IP-addresses that you want allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a URL Rewriter like [IIRF](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) to do this. Insert rules to return 404's or whatever you like to requests that come from disallowed IPs. This will work with any web app platform: PHP, Java, ASP.NET, RoR, static html or images, whatever.

The readme gives an example like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^(?!127.0.0.1)([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^/(?!redirected.htm)(.*)$      /redirected.htm
```

and it says:

> The above condition evaluates to true when the server-variable "REMOTE_ADDR" evaluates to an ip address which is NOT 127.0.0.1. The ?! is a zero-width negative lookahead, and the (.*) at the end of the regex is to catch any rubbish that sometimes appears in that variable.  The rule following the condition says, for any URL which is not "redirected.htm", map it to "redirected.htm".  This prevents endless re-writing. (You could also prevent endless rewriting with an [L] modifier flag).

This RewriteCond+RewriteRule redirects any externally originating requests to the IIS server.  You could do something similar for a specific set of whitelisted IPs.

IIRF is an ISAPI filter written in C, and is similar in philosophy to mod_rewrite.  It works with IIS5, 6, or 7. You will need admin access to set it up. You don't need to "program it", but there is a ini file that has similar syntax to .htaccess (specifically for the mod_rewrite rules).

IIRF is free and open source.